# Button image with Bootstrap 3 buttons

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a page with Bootstrap 3, I'm using standard buttons with different colors/shading (generated in a Bootstrap Button Generator). I'm trying to use an image so that it will be the background of the button, and still scale horizontally inside the containers.

The problem with using the standard methods that I was able to find is that the button appears as an image inside the bootstrap button. Maybe this is doable without bootstrap buttons, and if it works, no problem with me.

Comment: You can have them scale, just make a class that has 100% width and apply it to the buttons :)

Comment: @Aibrean The problem with just putting a background-image and 100% width is that only a part of the image appears, and that depends on the text of the button. I'd want to make all the borders appear, all the time - maybe there is some way to change the borders of a Bootstrap button?

Comment: Create a simple fiddle or show your code, so that it will be easy to answer the question ?

Answer (score 1):

After a while of tinkering, I was able to use it with the background-size (100% as @Aibrean mentioned) and background-repeat set as no-repeat.